# Is there a panel that shows me employment?

Tags: cities-skylines

I was looking through all the information in the game and it seems that there is no panel that shows me the difference between employed and unemployed people. This information is kind of important to plan my RCI.

**Where is the panel that shows me unemployment rates in Cities Skyline?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may take some time to unlock it, but after you've passed enough milestones there will be a population info view in the info panel (top left button). It appears as a grey person pictogram, roughly halfway up on the left (5th up from the bottom as of version 1.4). This shows the current percentage that are unemployed.

Additionally, if you press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or click on the menu button at the top right, you can open the statistics menu where you can see your employment rate over time (after choosing the option from the tick list on the right).